# How to access all of child's state from Parent Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a parent widget called createRoutineScreen and it has 7 similar children widget called RoutineFormCard. RoutineFormCard is a form and which has a state _isPostSuccesful of boolean type to tell whether the form is saved to database or not. Now, I have to move to the other screen from createRoutine only when all of it's 7 children has _isPostSuccesful true. How can I access all of children's state from createRoutineScreen widget?

My Code is:

```
 class CreateRoutineScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  final String userID;

  CreateRoutineScreen({this.userID});
  //TITLE TEXT
  final Text titleSection = Text(
      'Create a Routine',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 25,
      )
  );

  final List<Map> weekDays = [
    {"name":"Sunday", "value":1},
    {"name":"Monday", "value":2},
    {"name":"Tuesday", "value":3},
    {"name":"Wednesday", "value":4},
    {"name":"Thursday", "value":5},
    {"name":"Friday", "value":6},
    {"name":"Saturday", "value":7},
  ];

  @override
  _CreateRoutineScreenState createState() => _CreateRoutineScreenState();
}



class _CreateRoutineScreenState extends State<CreateRoutineScreen> {


  Routine routine;
  Future<List<dynamic>> _exercises;
  dynamic selectedDay;
  int _noOfRoutineSaved;
  List _keys = [];


   Future<List<dynamic>>_loadExercisesData()async{
    String url = BASE_URL+ "exercises";
    var res = await http.get(url);
    var exercisesList = Exercises.listFromJSON(res.body);
    //var value = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    return exercisesList;
  }


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _exercises = _loadExercisesData();
    _noOfRoutineSaved = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< 7; i++){
      _keys.add(UniqueKey());
    }
  }

  void _changeNoOfRoutineSaved(int a){
    setState(() {
      _noOfRoutineSaved= _noOfRoutineSaved + a;
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_noOfRoutineSaved);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:Text("Create a Routine"),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Done"),
              onPressed: (){
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0,left: 10,right: 10,bottom: 10),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _exercises,
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.weekDays.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return RoutineFormCard(
                      weekDay: widget.weekDays[index]["name"],
                      exerciseList: snapshot.data,
                      userID : widget.userID,
                      changeNoOfRoutineSaved:_changeNoOfRoutineSaved,
                      key:_keys[index]
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            else if(snapshot.hasError){
              return SnackBar(
              content: Text(snapshot.error),
              );
            }
            else{
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                )
              );
            }
          }, 
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my child widget is:

```
class RoutineFormCard extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function createRoutineState;
  final String weekDay;
  final List<dynamic> exerciseList;
  final String userID;
  final Function changeNoOfRoutineSaved;

  RoutineFormCard({this.createRoutineState, 
    this.weekDay, this.exerciseList, this.changeNoOfRoutineSaved,
    this.userID, Key key}):super(key:key);

  @override
  _RoutineFormCardState createState() => _RoutineFormCardState();
}

class _RoutineFormCardState extends State<RoutineFormCard> {

  bool _checkBoxValue= false;
  List<int> _selectedExercises;
  bool _inAsyncCall;
  bool   _successfulPost;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _selectedExercises = [];
    _inAsyncCall = false;
    _successfulPost= false;


  }

  void onSaveClick()async{

    setState(() {
     _inAsyncCall = true; 
    });

    String url = BASE_URL + "users/routine";

    List selectedExercises = _selectedExercises.map((item){
      return widget.exerciseList[item].value;
    }).toList();

    String dataToSubmit = jsonEncode({
      "weekDay":widget.weekDay,
      "userID": widget.userID==null?"5e9eb190b355c742c887b88d":widget.userID,
      "exercises": selectedExercises
    });

    try{
      var res =await  http.post(url, body: dataToSubmit,
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"});

        if(res.statusCode==200){
          print("Succesful ${res.body}");
          widget.changeNoOfRoutineSaved(1);
          setState(() {
           _inAsyncCall = false;
           _successfulPost = true; 
          });

        }
        else{
            print("Not succesful ${res.body}");
            setState(() {
             _inAsyncCall = false; 
            });
        }



    }catch(err){
        setState(() {
          _inAsyncCall = false; 
        });
        print(err);

    }

  }


  Widget saveAndEditButton(){
    if(_inAsyncCall){
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    else if(_successfulPost)
    {
      return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.black,),
        onPressed: (){
          widget.changeNoOfRoutineSaved(-1);
          setState(() {
           _successfulPost = false; 
          });
        },
      );
    }
    else{
      return FlatButton(child: Text("Save"),
            onPressed: !_checkBoxValue&&_selectedExercises.length==0?null:onSaveClick,);
    }
  }

  //Card Header
  Widget cardHeader(){
    return  AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.weekDay, style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Raleway",
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Colors.black,),
        ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        saveAndEditButton()    
      ],
      backgroundColor: Colors.lime[400],
    );
  }


  Widget cardBody(){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Rest Day"),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: _checkBoxValue,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        _checkBoxValue = value;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            _checkBoxValue?Container():
            SearchableDropdown.multiple(
            hint: "Select Exercise",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            items: widget.exerciseList.map<DropdownMenuItem>((item){
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item.name), value: item
              );
            }).toList(),
            selectedItems: _selectedExercises,
            onChanged: (values){
              setState(() {
              _selectedExercises = values;
              });
            },
            isExpanded: true,
            dialogBox: true,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("<><><><><><><><><><><>${widget.weekDay} called");
    return Card(
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: Form(
        key: GlobalKey(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
          cardHeader(),
          _successfulPost?Container():cardBody()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried callBack from parent widget which increases or decrease no of form saved from each of the child widget. It does the work but, when one form is saved, parent state is modified and all other children got rebuild which is unnecessary in my opionion. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: I think using ChangeNotifier and Provider in your case will be more elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `GlobalKey` instead of `UniqueKey` for each `RoutineFormCard`. It will help you to access the state of each `RoutineFormCard`. You can do it like this :

```dart
// 1. In the top of your CreateRoutineScreen file, add this line (make your RoutineFormCardState class public before)
final List<GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>> routineFormCardKeys = <GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>>[
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
  GlobalKey<RoutineFormCardState>(),
];

// 2. Then construct your RoutineFormCard using the right key
RoutineFormCard(
  weekDay: widget.weekDays[index]["name"],
  exerciseList: snapshot.data,
  userID : widget.userID,
  changeNoOfRoutineSaved:_changeNoOfRoutineSaved,
  key: routineFormCardKeys[index]
);

// 3. Now you can create a method in CreateRoutineScreen which will check the state of all RoutineFormCard
bool _allRoutineFormCardsCompleted() {
  bool result = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    result = result && routineFormCardKeys[i].currentState.isPostSuccessful;

  return result;
}


// 4. Finally use the result of the previous method where you want to move on another page
```

*I'm sharing a quick idea to solve your problem, I've not tested it, but I'm ready to improve the answer if needed*

Hope this will help!